# How do I execute this assembly code?

Tags: assembly

I've written this simple code in JavaScript and use d8 to show the assembly code. Now, I want to execute that assembly code but I'm unable to do it.

Here's my code

```
print('Hello')
```

And this is the assembly I get from d8

```
--- Raw source ---
print('Hello');


--- Code ---
source_position = 0
kind = FUNCTION
compiler = full-codegen
Instructions (size = 180)
0x13fb4a04740     0  55             push rbp
0x13fb4a04741     1  4889e5         REX.W movq rbp,rsp
0x13fb4a04744     4  56             push rsi
0x13fb4a04745     5  57             push rdi
0x13fb4a04746     6  488b4f2f       REX.W movq rcx,[rdi+0x2f]
0x13fb4a0474a    10  488b490f       REX.W movq rcx,[rcx+0xf]
0x13fb4a0474e    14  83411b01       addl [rcx+0x1b],0x1
0x13fb4a04752    18  41ff75a0       push [r13-0x60]
0x13fb4a04756    22  493ba5200c0000 REX.W cmpq rsp,[r13+0xc20]
0x13fb4a0475d    29  7305           jnc 36  (0x13fb4a04764)
0x13fb4a0475f    31  e8dce2f4ff     call StackCheck  (0x13fb4952a40)    ;; code: BUILTIN
0x13fb4a04764    36  48b80000000004000000 REX.W movq rax,0x400000000
0x13fb4a0476e    46  e86dfcffff     call 0x13fb4a043e0       ;; code: LOAD_GLOBAL_IC
0x13fb4a04773    51  50             push rax
0x13fb4a04774    52  49ba1123f8ee15360000 REX.W movq r10,0x3615eef82311    ;; object: 0x3615eef82311 <undefined>
0x13fb4a0477e    62  4152           push r10
0x13fb4a04780    64  49ba19b92ab6eb2a0000 REX.W movq r10,0x2aebb62ab919    ;; object: 0x2aebb62ab919 <String[5]: Hello>
0x13fb4a0478a    74  4152           push r10
0x13fb4a0478c    76  48ba0000000002000000 REX.W movq rdx,0x200000000
0x13fb4a04796    86  488b7c2410     REX.W movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
0x13fb4a0479b    91  e820ffffff     call 0x13fb4a046c0       ;; code: CALL_IC
0x13fb4a047a0    96  488b75f8       REX.W movq rsi,[rbp-0x8]
0x13fb4a047a4   100  4883c408       REX.W addq rsp,0x8
0x13fb4a047a8   104  488945e8       REX.W movq [rbp-0x18],rax
0x13fb4a047ac   108  488b45e8       REX.W movq rax,[rbp-0x18]
0x13fb4a047b0   112  48bbd1ba2ab6eb2a0000 REX.W movq rbx,0x2aebb62abad1    ;; object: 0x2aebb62abad1 Cell for 6144
0x13fb4a047ba   122  83430bd1       addl [rbx+0xb],0xd1
0x13fb4a047be   126  791f           jns 159  (0x13fb4a047df)
0x13fb4a047c0   128  50             push rax
0x13fb4a047c1   129  e8fae1f4ff     call InterruptCheck  (0x13fb49529c0)    ;; code: BUILTIN
0x13fb4a047c6   134  58             pop rax
0x13fb4a047c7   135  48bbd1ba2ab6eb2a0000 REX.W movq rbx,0x2aebb62abad1    ;; object: 0x2aebb62abad1 Cell for 6144
0x13fb4a047d1   145  49ba0000000000180000 REX.W movq r10,0x180000000000
0x13fb4a047db   155  4c895307       REX.W movq [rbx+0x7],r10
0x13fb4a047df   159  c9             leavel
0x13fb4a047e0   160  c20800         ret 0x8
0x13fb4a047e3   163  498b45a0       REX.W movq rax,[r13-0x60]
0x13fb4a047e7   167  e9c4ffffff     jmp 112  (0x13fb4a047b0)
0x13fb4a047ec   172  0f1f4000       nop
```

Now I would like to execute that assembly code I get this error:

> cc -s print.s
>       print.s:1:1: error: 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode

This is my print.s

```
push rbp
movq rbp,rsp
push rsi
push rdi
movq rcx,[rdi+0x2f]
movq rcx,[rcx+0xf]
addl [rcx+0x1b],0x1
push [r13-0x60]
cmpq rsp,[r13+0xc20]
jnc 36
call StackCheck
movq rax,0x400000000
call 0x13fb4a043e0
push rax
movq r10,0x3615eef82311
push r10
movq r10,0x2aebb62ab919
push r10
movq rdx,0x200000000
movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
call 0x13fb4a046c0
movq rsi,[rbp-0x8]
addq rsp,0x8
movq [rbp-0x18],rax
movq rax,[rbp-0x18]
movq rbx,0x2aebb62abad1
addl [rbx+0xb],0xd1
jns 159
push rax
call InterruptCheck
pop rax
movq rbx,0x2aebb62abad1
movq r10,0x180000000000
movq [rbx+0x7],r10
leavel
ret 0x8
movq rax,[r13-0x60]
jmp 112
nop
```

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: You're on OS X, right?  Other OSes do allow absolute addresses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on such an incorrect premise that there's no useful answer other than "you can't take an asm fragment from a Javascript JIT and execute it as a stand-alone program".  Especially not when it prints something instead of just calculating an input from an output.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take a snippet from a program with fixed pointers, copy-paste that and expect it to work.

Your snippet will never work.
It references absolute addresses that are only valid within the context of the original program it was executed in.
The next time the original program executes the addresses will likely be different because of ASLR, quite beside the fact that all programs in OSX must be relocatable; i.e. fixed addresses do not *exist* in OSX.
In any case you point to run-time code that is simply not present in your copy-paste snippet.

You need to learn how to write a stand-alone 'hallo world' assembly program.

There are 100's of tutorials detailing how to do this, e.g.: http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/assembly-hello-world-for-os-x

> ```
>  hello.asm - a "hello, world" program using NASM
>
> section .text
>
> global mystart                ; make the main function externally visible
>
> mystart:
>
> ; 1 print "hello, world"
>
>     ; 1a prepare the arguments for the system call to write
>     push dword mylen          ; message length                           
>     push dword mymsg          ; message to write
>     push dword 1              ; file descriptor value
>
>     ; 1b make the system call to write
>     mov eax, 0x4              ; system call number for write
>     sub esp, 4                ; OS X (and BSD) system calls needs "extra space" on stack
>     int 0x80                  ; make the actual system call
>
>     ; 1c clean up the stack
>     add esp, 16               ; 3 args * 4 bytes/arg + 4 bytes extra space = 16 bytes
>
> ; 2 exit the program
>
>     ; 2a prepare the argument for the sys call to exit
>     push dword 0              ; exit status returned to the operating system
>
>     ; 2b make the call to sys call to exit
>     mov eax, 0x1              ; system call number for exit
>     sub esp, 4                ; OS X (and BSD) system calls needs "extra space" on stack
>     int 0x80                  ; make the system call
>
>     ; 2c no need to clean up the stack because no code here would executed: already exited
>
> section .data
>
>   mymsg db "hello, world", 0xa  ; string with a carriage-return
>   mylen equ $-mymsg             ; string length in bytes
> ```

If you want to write assembly code running under OSX you'll also need to learn [how the OSX API works](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/navigation/).